# Why are selfdestructs used in contract programming?

Tags: contract-design, selfdestruct

I'm reading bits and pieces that selfdestructs within contracts are a good thing.  Can someone explain what the benefits are of doing a contract selfdestruct when it comes to Ethereum programming? Is there a difference if you're using different clients or implementations, or languages?

Comment: This question is very unclear. Are you asking about contract suicides, or clients or what?

Comment: Sorry about that - contract.

Comment: The last sentence is the confusing part, because the go client is a client, solidity is a language, and python could be referring to the python client, or possibly to serpent, the python-like Ethereum language

Comment: tried again - let me know if it's more clear - just trying to see if there are any differences within each implementation?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Selfdestructs in Ethereum are an operation (an OPCODE actually) at the EVM level, independent of what language or client you are using.

For example, calling `selfdestruct(address)` sends all of the contract's current balance to `address`.

This is useful when you are finished with a contract, because it costs far less gas than just sending the balance with `address.send(this.balance)`.

In fact, the SELFDESTRUCT opcode uses **negative gas** because the operation frees up space on the blockchain by clearing all of the contract's data.

This negative gas deducts from the total gas cost of the transaction, so if you're doing some clean-up operations first, SELFDESTRUCT can reduce your gas costs.

Comment: What happens if you try to call suicided contract? Is it state back to zero or does EVM set some flag telling this contract is no longer here?

Comment: What happens if you send ether to the contract which is suicided?

Comment: The balance of the address increases, but since there is no code at the address anymore, the ETH just gets stuck. That ETH is then essentially burned.

Answer (score 51):

*Note: this question originally asked about the `suicide` opcode, which has become `selfdestruct` in the meantime as per [EIP6](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-6.md).*

`selfdestruct` is the encouraged term and may be found in newer Solidity and Serpent code.  It is the same API and behavior, as described in the other answers, and is an alias for `suicide`.

[EIP6](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-6.md) describes the motivation:

> The primary reason for us to change the term suicide is to show that
>   people matter more than code and Ethereum is a mature enough of a
>   project to recognize the need for a change. Suicide is a heavy subject
>   and we should make every effort possible to not affect those in our
>   development community who suffer from depression or who have recently
>   lost someone to suicide.

Comment: selfdestruct alias has been applied to the codebases of Solidity and Serpent and is the preferred term to use.

Answer (score 32):

The `selfdestruct()` function and the relative OPCODE are used when you have a contract that has a bug or an unwanted behaviour and you want to get rid of it.

The `selfdestruct(address)` is a better version as @tjaden-hess pointed out, when you have a payable contracts (contracts that receive ethers) the ethers will be redirected to `address` which is a big win.

When you interact with a selfdestructed contract NOTE this: If you send a transaction and/or funds to it then your **funds are LOST**. Be sure to not send funds or other transactions to it after self-destructing a contract.

That's an issue you always have to keep in mind when developing apps that use contracts with a selfdestruct function, be sure the address of the contract is *removed* from your app after `selfdestruct()` has been called on the contract, maybe you can always call a *getter* method to see if the contract responds with a valid value before sending a transaction and/or transferring ethers to it.

**Update**

The name of the method is now `selfdestruct`. [We have some description of it in the new solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=selfdestruct#contract-related).

Here's a [post from r/ethereum about suicide](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3ilpvb/what_happens_when_you_send_ether_to_a_postsuicide/) with more infos and a small discussion about it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: will a self-destruct smart contract no longer exists in blockchain?. I think, people can still see it, but it's a non-functionality smart contract. Is that true?

Comment: @ender - yes, the purpose/benefit of `selfdestruct()` is that if you have a dangerously buggy contract you can "terminate" it

Comment: @makevoid thanks, I found the answer on the same date. Ppl can see it after destructed. For example https://etherscan.io/address/0x863df6bfa4469f3ead0be8f9f2aae51c91a907b4#code

Comment: @ender in the etherscan (or etherchain) contract page you see the contract source only if it's uploaded by a user (it gets compared and verified by etherscan byw). The only way to interact with that contract / code is to fetch the bytecode from the block in which it was deployed thou and re-deploy it if you want to "resurrect" it, you still the ABI and you won't be able tor estore any state / ethers / tokens sent to the contract.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO `selfdestruct` is a bad thing that should never be introduced.  It breaks contract's immutability principle and introduces many problems:

1. It allows successfully sending ether to contract that tries to disallow incoming ether transfer (have no payable functions)
2. If allows sending ether to a contract that tries to actively react on incoming ether transfers, in such a way that the contract will not notice the transfer
3. While it does send all the ether from contract's balance to specified address, it does not sent tokens and other assets
4. Assets sent to a contract after `selfdestruct` are lost in most cases, checking that contract is not selfdestructed before the transfer does not help much, because transfer may be frontrunned with `selfdestruct`
5. It allows modifying bytecode of a deployed smart contract ([EIP-1014](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1014.md))

Answer (score 3):

> Why are `selfdestructs` used in contract programming

*Once a contract is created on the Ethereum blockchain it cannot be modified.*

1. Each block in the blockchain commits to all of the transactions in
   the block and the order that they are in. It does this by including
   the hash of all of the transactions in the block header, which is
   then part of the data that is hashed for the proof of work.
2. Modifying a smart contract in a block will change the hash of all of
   the transactions which ultimately changes the hash of the block
   header. This will likely make the block header's hash have an
   invalid proof of work. Thus in order to modify the transaction, you
   would have to redo the block's proof of work, i.e. remine the block.
3. Furthermore, the block header includes the hash of the previous
   block. So if you want to change a transaction which would contain
   the smart contract eventually , you will need to also remine all of
   the blocks following the block which contains the transaction(smart
   contract) you modified. Lastly, your set of modified blocks are
   actually a blockchain fork. In order to get it to be accepted by the
   rest of the network, your fork will need to have more cumulative
   work than the current blockchain, which effectively means that your
   fork needs to be longer than the current blockchain.

> BENEFITS OF USING SELFDESTRUCT

```
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     Benefit     |                                       Reasoning                                       |
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Stop Execution  | If you no longer want the contract running, you can selfdestruct it to “turn it off”. |
| Eliminate Bugs  | (Similar to above). You can kill off smart contracts that are buggy.                  |
| Lower Gas Price | It costs less gas to selfdestruct a contract.                                         |
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```