# Can you selfdestruct a contract more than once?

Tags: solidity, selfdestruct

I read the [Contract's state after a selfdestruct](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10793/contracts-state-after-a-selfdestruct) thread, but it doesn't answer the question whether you can selfdestruct multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may depend on what your definition of "contract" is. :-)

Once a contract is selfdestructed, there is no code at that address anymore, so it can't execute a `SELFDESTRUCT` again.

However, due to the existence of `CREATE2`, you can now potentially deploy *new* code to the *same address* as the previous contract. That new code could contain a `SELFDESTRUCT` opcode. This means that the same *address* can run a `SELFDESTRUCT` multiple times, but whether it's really the same "contract" or not is a question of how you define that term.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As per Steven's comment below, you *cannot* `sefldestruct` more than once because no `SELFDESTRUCT` opcode will be executed again (there's no code at that address anymore).

---

Yes, you can, with a few caveats:

1. During the first selfdestruct, the state of the contract is erased and will remain like that forever. You will be able to call the methods without reverting though.
2. The Ether balance will only get depleted the first time.

Let's see it in action:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.11;

contract Counter {

    uint256 public counter;

    function increment() external {
        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    function doSelfDestruct() external {
        selfdestruct(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
    }

    function() external payable {}
}
```

Steps:

1. Deploy the contract on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org).
2. Call `increment`.
3. Read `counter`. Should be 1.
4. Transfer Ether to the contract (set around 30,000 gas).
5. Call `doSelfDestruct`.
6. The Ether balance and its state should both be gone.
7. Call `increment` again.
8. Read `counter`. Should be 0.
9. Repeat steps #3 and #4. The balance should not be transferred again.

Comment: Although I agree that the answer is "yes", this example doesn't seem right to me. The second time you attempt to call `doSelfDestruct()`, no actual `SELFDESTRUCT` opcode execute. You can send whatever data you want to the contract address, but because there's no longer any code, no code will be executed.

Comment: Thanks @smarx I updated the answer