# is selfdestruct a good practice?

Tags: selfdestruct

A contract after selfdestruct cannot manage transactions, and as such any ether sent to it is lost. Wouldn't be better to switch to a contract defined state "dismissed" and reject any ether sent by mistake when in such a state?

Comment: Check the accepted answer in https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/315/why-are-selfdestructs-used-in-contract-programming .. It is generally good to use that option since it frees up space and as mentioned **uses negative gas** so you save on gas too

Answer (score 2):

*In my opinion*, no, self-destruct is usually not a good practice. As you say, it creates dangerous voids on the blockchain where:

1. no one has a signing key,
2. there is no contract code, and
3. possibly users believe there is a contract there.

Any funds sent to such an address will be unrecoverable which is the same as destroyed.

A conscientious developer can completely disable a contract without creating such a void.

```
contract Pausable is Ownable {

  bool public isRunning;

  modifier onlyWhenRunning {
    require(isRunning);
    _;
  }

  function stopContract() public onlyOwner {
    isRunning = false;
  }
}
```

Check out OpenZeppelin for a more complete implementation of the pattern.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually OpenZeppelin has a Destructible contract which calls selfdestruct(...)

Comment: I'm not against using it with extreme caution such as in the context of upgradable contracts. What concerns me is using it as a standard operating procedure. It's often not the optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that much better code snippet.

Answer (score -2):

You can implement this functionality by yourself. You can implement a modifier before the selfdestruct instruction to check the quantity of ether owned by the contract.
This way, the contract could be "destroyed" only if it does not own ether.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The question was about best practice and what happens to sent Ether *after* the contract has been destroyed - own implementation doesn't help in this case.

Comment: True. But can we talk about good practice if the functionality described is the only one available?

Comment: Davide is saying something different: he thinks to leave a “reject ether” function in place, fully working, instead of self destruction. I can say that self destructing is useful to clean the blockchain, freeing space. If you restrict the functionality of a contract only, all the code space remains occupied... anyway I understand the point.

Comment: Ok, I got it, sorry for the misunderstanding.