# Simple smart contracts to make a bet

Tags: ether, dapps

I would like to create a simple smart contract between me and a couple of friends (basically, I'm putting money on the line and betting them that I will do something that they don't think I'll do.)

We want to write a simple (arbitration bound) smart contract that will allow us to put ether (or whatever, not bound to ether if someone knows a better platform) into 'escrow' so that we can bet on the outcome and then deliver the funds (we've had problems with people not paying afterwards because they 'weren't serious' about the bet, this would make them be serious).

Any recommendations for apps/dapps/platforms/annoyingly complicated solidity scripts that could do this for me?

Comment: I assume by "arbitration bound" you mean there's a trusted third party who will decide the outcome of the bet. If so, why don't you just give that person the money and let them give it to the bet winner later?

Comment: By arbitration bound I mean that we will argue about the meaning of words until someone gets angry. And no, then we couldn't overcomplicate it.

Comment: I want an excuse to play with ethereum smart contracts. Why the downvote?

Comment: @ConnorMcCormick is asking for an example of a simple betting contract which I think is a totally reasonable request. I do not understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest useful example that I could come up with is something along these lines. This is a contract where the participants can deposit ether to the contract and the admin can settle the bet and determine who has won. Initially the contract creator is admin but this can be changed prior to any funds being deposited. This contract only allows for one winner. If the admin is another contract, complete trust in one single person is not necessary.

I have not tested the below code, so you should only consider it inspiration. You want to test it before you deposit real money into this.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract Exchange {
  address public admin;

  modifier onlyAdmin {
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    _;
  }

  function Exchange() {
    admin = msg.sender;
  }

  function changeAdmin(address _newAdmin) onlyAdmin {
    require(_newAdmin != address(0));
    admin = _newAdmin();
  }

  function deposit() payable {
  }

  function settle(address _winner) onlyAdmin {
    selfdestruct(_winner);
  }
}
```

The constructor `Exchange()` sets the class variable `admin` of type `address` to the address that publishes this contract onto the blockchain. The admin can give this role to a person or an Ethereum smart contract through the method `changeAdmin`.

The participants can then deposit funds into the contract by calling `deposit` when they trust the admin and the admin can settle the bet by calling `settle`. The `settle` method sends the balance of this contract to the argument with which the method is called as is described [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/347/6106). Only the creator of the contract can call the settle method. The `settle` method also deletes this contract from the blockchain and refunds some of the gas that the admin incurred when calling `settle`.

You can build a lot more logic into the betting contract, if you like. You could for example ensure that the admin can only pay the funds out to the participants and not to himself (which is possible in the above contract). It is questionable how much sense this contract makes as long as you have not done this. And you can opt to make the bet in ERC20 tokens instead of, as above, in Ether.

Comment: This is a very good starting point, in my opinion. I would avoid `selfdestruct` in favor of Pausable and use a standard Ownable with transferrable ownership (admin). When the "admin" is itself another contract, then the betting and the arbitration can be approached as separate concerns.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will change my proposal accordingly.

Comment: I made the admin role transferable. Did you want to make the contract pausable so it could be used for other bets in the future?

Comment: It's good to keep things brief here, imo, so the answer stays on point. `selfdestruct` creates dangerous voids on the blockchain so I wouldn't use it in production.

Comment: `contract Betting is Pausable` would take care of multiple concerns. The contract would be stopped instead of destroyed.

Comment: I understand. But since @ConnorMcCormick is asking for a simple example, I would prefer to avoid inheritance.

Comment: @ThorkilVærge thank you very much. I agree with you that, for now, simplicity trumps functionality. I will study this (and study pausability) and give it a test. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @RobHitchensB9lab recommends that you don't use the selfdestruct instruction since it leaves voids in the blockchain allowing users to send assets to deleted contracts. These assets will not be recoverable and he is probably right in his recommendation.